# include partial in nanoc [haml]

Tags: layout, haml, render, partial, nanoc

I have this in my Rules file:

```
compile '/gallery/' do  
  filter :haml
  layout :'gallery'
end  
...
compile '/' do  
  filter :haml
  layout :'default'
end  
...
route '/gallery/' do  
  nil
end
...
route '*' do  
  item.identifier.chop + '.' +item[:extension]
end
```

, so now my content/index.html goes through haml filter and compiles as output/index.html
all well and good.
My content/gallery.html holds this code which also goes through haml:

```
#gallery-container  

%ul.items-small  
  %li.item  
    - @item.children.each do |img|  
      %a{:href => "#{img.path}"}  

%ul.items-big  
  %li.item-big  
    - @item.children.each do |img|  
      %a{:href => "#"}  
        %figure  
          %img{:src => "#{img.path(:rep => :thumbnail)}"}  
          %figcaption.img-caption Caption
```

,it gathers some images in `content/gallery/` folder and when I set routing to `output/gallery/index.html`(to see the preview output spit out) I do get what I want, so all well and good still.

But now I would like to use that generated code as partial in my `content/index.html`, however
when I try to include it like `=render 'gallery'` I do not get my expected code. In turn I get error message `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`.

What should be in my `layouts/gallery.html` file?, if I put there `<%= yield %>` I get the above error, If i remove `=render 'gallery'` there is no error,
But if I put some text in `layouts/gallery.html` and have again that `=render 'gallery'` in my index.html I get literally that text in `layouts/gallery.html`, so it gets included and without error. So should I <%= yield %> that gallery code I am expecting into `layouts/gallery.html` and then call =render 'gallery' from index.html?? But that does not work. Also that `layouts/default.html` already has its own yield which is working, and then I try to use that =render in item which would be compiled through that yield. Am i doing it wrong way? I am lost!

All of my layouts file are `:erb` filtered.

So my question would be how to include this partial. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some trying and erroring it seems that it should be done like this,

```
= items["/gallery/"].compiled_content
```

, if I put that into my `content/index.html.haml` file instead, I do get results which I expect, and my `content/gallery.html.haml` renders itself on that place. I am not yet shure, where would I use `render` for partials, and what is the difference in using that and this one I used here.

Comment: I suspect render only works on files that are there when you compile the site. That is why you need to hook in to nanocs mechanism for this.

Comment: hoppely one day this will clearup for me :), thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the code I found another solution to this.

The render method is part of `Helpers::Rendering`, if you look at the source code you see that it calls `filter_for_layout` from the rules ([github](https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/blob/4.4.3/lib/nanoc/helpers/rendering.rb#L40)).

You therefore just need to add the following to your `Rules` file:

```
layout '/gallery/', :haml, encoding: 'utf-8'
```

That way as the gallery layout is rendered it will pass through the haml filter like the other layouts.